# Accessing AdvertisingIdClient in Play Services 9.2.1

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I added `play-services-ads-lite` to my project, but apparently it doesn't contain

`com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient`.

which of the following libraries do I have to include?

[image: play Services libs]

Comment: Managed to find an answer to this question?